# Help on calculating spoke length

Tags: wheels, rims

I am going to replace my bent hub on my MTB. The hub is Novatec D042SB and the rim which I am going to order is Sun Ringle Inferno 25 29er. Since my hub is not so popular there are not any default dimensions available in online spoke calculator databases. I cannot take apart all the stuff on the wheel for precise measurements and that's why I have to ask for your help. I have used several calculators and all of them gave me different result ranging from 290mm to 294mm.

Here are the dimensions of my hub in Novatec's official website.

Flange to Flange 58.4mm

Flange Diameter 58mm

Over Locknut 135mm

Offset of centers 6.8 mm

Rim ERD 602 mm

If anyone has experience with building a wheel, please help me to determine the exact length of the spoke

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than quoting figures for the right and left flange distances from the Locknut centerline distance, they quote a "flange to flange" distance, along with an offset, for some mysterious reason.

This image: http://issuu.com/novatectaiwan/docs/novatec_hub_dimensions should help translate their "Flange to Flange" and offset figures to be right and left flange distances. In the case of this hub, your left and right flange distances are:

```
Wl = (F.T.F/2 + Offset) = 36.00mm
Wr = (F.T.F/2 - Offset) = 22.40mm
```

Using the dt swiss calculator, I calculate 292 and 291mm spokes for building a triple-cross wheel with your selected components.

Comment: There is not an option for 291 mm spoke here at Chain Reaction Cycles. So which one should I choose 292 and 290 or both 292 ?

http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/am/en/dt-swiss-competition-db-silver-spokes-18-pack/rp-prod91857

Comment: @AbrahamyanSamvel: see if there is already a question on that topic, if not, post a new question.